# Azure site dll compatibility issue - System.Web.WebPages.Razor

Tags: azure, razor, dll, compatibility

I'm building a test website in azure, I'm getting an issue in Azure site, Where as my local code published to a folder and setup in IIS is working fine. I work on vs2015. code written in C#. Error is below one. Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. Please help in this. Thanks
cr

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at the referenced version? Is the referenced version deployed?

Answer (score 1):

Is the dll in your solution set as copy local? (go to references, right mouse button and then properties.)
If not set it to copy local.

Alternatively:
Do you use different versions of the dll in your solution?
Then set a bindingredirect to the latest version and be sure to use the correct one in your application. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thottams/archive/2007/01/30/introduction-to-versioning-and-bindingredirect.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what RoteS answered, if you are using MVC on VS2015 and you are deploying to Azure by [Continuous Integration](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2015/11/24/automating-deployment-on-azure-web-apps/), why not reference the [MVC Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.mvc/) instead? You won't need to commit or copy that DLL around, and Azure (Kudu) will handle the package restore for you when it's deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies. 
I've tried by two options
1.Setting copylocal = true 
2.Instlling  Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.2.3
But still the problem was there. It works on Local system when published. 
But it was not working in Azure. seemed to be some publish issue.

Finally as 3rd step,

I've taken all the mvc related dlls and copied to Bin mannually, referred from this location instead of the package location. 
Set the option - copyLocal = true

It worked fine :)

Thanks.